# Node JS Server(Socket IO) does not react to requests on heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I uploaded my node js server to herokuapp but if I try to use the chat it does not work.
But the client connects to the server and the console shows this

```
2018-10-11T14:01:02.704673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myProject request_id=7a111f8c-c090-43d4-8f69-ae32c2a6e62e fwd=":)" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=115 protocol=https
```

I deletet some infos but this is all that shows up.

If I run the server on my maschine everythings works fine. But when I try to emit an event from the client to the server nothings happens.

I use a C# Lib to access the server through this socket = `IO.Socket("https://myproject.herokuapp.com/");`

Comment: Try removing the slash at the end in `IO.Socket("https://myproject.herokuapp.com/");`

Comment: still not working, only connecting and disconnecting works :/

Comment: the sever uses the port 3000 but if I use this IO.Socket("https://myproject.herokuapp.com:3000"); it does not even connect

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL cert?